# what cordinates should be given to making the line curve on a canvas

Tags: javascript, canvas, html5-canvas

I have a canvas of dimensions `width = 100px` and `height = 150px`

I need to make curved lines by using the function `bezierCurveTo()`

**.html**

```
<canvas id = "canvas" width = "100" height = "150"></canvas>
```

**.ts**

```
var canvas = <HTMLCanvasElement>document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');

  ctx.strokeStyle = 'white';
  ctx.beginPath();
  ctx.lineWidth=3;
  ctx.moveTo(40,0);
  ctx.bezierCurveTo(); //what dimensions to be filled?
  ctx.lineTo(100,150)   
  ctx.stroke();
```

What dimesions to be filled in the function `bezierCurveTo()` in rdr to look curved line exactly in the screenshot provided.

[image]

Ingnore the dotted lines in the screenshot.

Comment: ctx.bezierCurveTo(30, 0, -70, 75, 100, 150);

Comment: @Fraser Can you tell me the coordinates for the exact mirror image of the screenshot along y-axis ? It would be useless if I write the same question for just the mirror image.

Comment: ctx.bezierCurveTo(70, 0, 170, 75, 0, 150);

Comment: @Fraser no its not working...I need to draw it as opposite staring from 80,0 and ends at 0,150..

Comment: It worked...:) thanks man

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heyaaaa

Disclaimer: I've never drawn to a plain 2d canvas before

I looked up the [bezierCurveTo()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/CanvasRenderingContext2D/bezierCurveTo) method and it has 6 arguments that it requires.

I then built this [CodePen](https://codepen.io/justrealmilk/pen/RMNyrX) for you.

```
var canvas = document.getElementById('canvas');
var ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
ctx.strokeStyle = 'black';
ctx.beginPath();
ctx.lineWidth=1;
//ctx.moveTo(40,0);
ctx.bezierCurveTo(30, 0, -70, 75, 100, 150);  //what dimensions to be filled?
//ctx.lineTo(100,150)   
ctx.stroke();
```

Let me know how it works out for ya

Comment: sort of some matching.. but not fully meeting the requirements

Comment: it should be curved from the middle.

Comment: Great...Cool..!

Comment: Can you tell me the coordinates for the exact mirror image of the screenshot alaong y-axis ? It would be useless if I write the same question for just the mirror image.